# Replace accented or special characters using sed or tr unix command using Unicode Code or Hex

Tags: unix, unicode, replace, sed

I wonder if I can use character set found in http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x&unicodeinhtml=hex to replace accented or special characters using sed or tr.

I have a script that uses sed command. Sometimes it does not work :(

it goes like this:

```
sed -e "s/\"//g" \
                -e "s/\'//g" \
                -e "s/[$]/S/g" \
                -e "s/%//g" \
                -e "s/&/E/g" \
                -e "s/@/a/g" \
                -e "s/\^//g" \
                -e "s/\`//g" \
                -e "s/|//g" \
                -e "s/~//g" \
                -e "s/¡/i/g" \
                -e "s/¨//g" \
                -e "s/\´//g" \
                -e "s/¢/c/g" \
                -e "s/£//g" \
                -e "s/§//g" \
                -e "s/¬//g" \
                -e "s/°/o/g" \
                -e "s/·/./g" \
                -e "s/¹/1/g" \
                -e "s/²/2/g" \
                -e "s/³/3/g" \
                -e "s/¿//g" \
                -e "s/ª/a/g" \
                -e "s/à/a/g" \
                -e "s/á/a/g" \
                -e "s/â/a/g" \
                -e "s/ã/a/g" \
                -e "s/ä/a/g" \
                -e "s/å/a/g" \
                -e "s/æ/ae/g" \
```

Os, I am thinking if I use hex or octal unicode codes to be used in sed, it would work. But I do not know how...

```
e.g. echo ¢ | sed 's/\x{00A2}/cent/g'
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: *Sometimes it does not work* -> If it is related to some cases, could you detail which ones make it fail?

Comment: For second question: try `echo ¢ | sed 's/\xC2\xA2/cent/g'`, works for me.

Comment: Thanks @Qeole but it did not work for me. I am using aix btw. My sed command will not work if the file I am trying to replace was not created in a UTF-8 w/o BOM format file. At least that was what I have observed.

Comment: *That*'s something you should definitely have precised. Can't you just reencode your file (or a copy of it) into UTF-8 first?

Answer (score 2):

## Your script

…works fine for me. Every substitution is performed as expected, except for one:

```
-e "s/\'//g" \
```

should be

```
-e "s/'//g" \
```

(There's no need to escape the single quote, your expression is between double quotes.)

Applied to a file containing

```
"'$%&@^`|~¡¨´¢£§¬°·¹²³¿ªàáâãäåæ
```

it ouputs:

```
  S E a   i  c   o.123 aaaaaaaae
```

(Without spaces. I added them to make it easier to compare orginialm pattern and substitution.)

## Hexa code

For replacing with hexadecimal code, use following syntax:

```
echo ¢ | sed 's/\xC2\xA2/cent/g'
```

Why is so? An hexadecimal value `XX` is given to sed with `\xXX` syntax (see `info sed`). And for your `¢` character, the third column of table on webpage you link gives `0xc2 0xa2`.

## Encoding

As you are trying to replace UTF-8 encoded characters, I assume your file uses UTF-8 encoding. If it is not, a quick solution would be to convert it (or a copy of it) into UTF-8 (e.g. with your favorite text editor).

Comment: And if you don’t know how to get those hexadecimal values for Unicode characters, then GNU `echo` can help: `echo -ne '\u00A0'|xxd`.